# Как задать отсчет времени от указаного?

Tags: php, дата

Как начать отсчет от заданного времени.
Для чего нужно?
На хостинге у меня сейчас 12:00 а у моего друга 04:00 утра.

Хочу вывести себе такую строчку, у друга сейчас 04:00 чтобы быть в курсе какое у него сейчас время.

Например в переменную занесу текущее время друга $drug = "04:00"; а дальше что то ничего не приходит на ум.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так, надеюсь поможет:

```
<?php
  date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); //по Гринвичу, можно опустить
  $time = time(); //текущее время на сервере
  $offset = 4; //смещение для друга
  $time += $offset * 3600; //его реальное время
  echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
```

На самом деле, гуглится за одну минуту.

Answer (score 0):

Я сделал такое решение. Может пригодится кому.

Получаю смещение время при помощи JQuery.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   a = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
   $("#timezone").val(a);   
});
</script>
```

Деле вставляю значение в скрытое поле которое находится у меня в форме авторизации.

```
<input type="hidden" name="timezone" id="timezone" value ="" />
```

Дальше работаю с PHP. Просто где проверка данных с формы авторизации делаю еще не большую проверку.

```
        if(isset($_POST["timezone"])) { 
            if($pr_ruser["timezone"] == "") {

                $timezone = $_POST["timezone"];
                $prruser_id = $pr_ruser["id"];

                $query_update = "UPDATE users SET timezone = '$timezone' WHERE id='$prruser_id'";
                $update_update = mysqli_query($db, $query_update) or die("Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($db));

            }

        }
```

Ну и дальше в нужном месте

```
        $user_time = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($timezone." hours"));
        $user_time = substr($user_time, -5, 5);
        if($user_time == "00:00"){
            $user_time = "<br><p class='user_time notime'>Время пользователя не определенно</p>";
        } else {
            $user_time = "<br><p class='user_time time'>Время пользователя - ".$user_time."</p>";
        }
```

Сюда получаю смещение пользователя `$timezone = $allusers["timezone"];` и дальше вывожу уже.  `$user_time = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($timezone." hours"));`